Can I put new holes in a TV mount for non-standard stud spacing?
I have a bracket for a full moving 65" TV.
My studs are 13" on center above the fireplace - I'm thinking of modifying my bracket to hit the studs on either side
Would effect the strength and effectiveness of the mount if I cut the two other holes to hit the two other studs?

You'd have to tell us something about your mount. A product link or clear photo is necessary. Otherwise we're just guessing. There's a very good chance that new holes are a perfectly viable solution.

I imagine that this will work well, post a photo of the part that mounts to the wall  so we can confirm that adding holes to it will not compromise its strenth.

Mounting to studs will be the most secure way to go about it.
Rather than modifying your mount, consider creating an "interface plate" with 3/4" plywood that can span the studs and provides you the flexibility to install your TV mount wherever it makes sense (preferably centered to your fireplace) without having to align the mount to studs.

We did something similar in our house, except we didn't want to have a big slab of plywood on the wall. So we just traced the board on the wall, cut a hole in the drywall, drilled the board to the studs and filled/painted so it was seamless. Still going strong 5 years later.

@ChellCPlus that's thorough!  But with 13 inch stud spacing it should hopefully not be necessary.

@jay613 it was a big ol TV so we went a little overboard. Its future proof I suppose, if we ever wanted to replace it with some giant 100" TV it would probably hold just fine.

I had to hang a large (old) mirror which was provided with two hooks on the back.  The hooks were factory installed and the back of the mirror has a printed warning/instruction on it to only use the provided hooks for hanging.  The hooks were apparently installed "by eye" as they are not spaced a multiple of 16" or even level.  Installed a piece of 1X4 to span 4 studs, then drove screws to meet the bizarrely-placed hooks.


I have a bracket for a full moving 65" TV.

In my experience, anything larger that a 32 inch TV rarely needs to be swiveled.
Regardless, doing so requires immense pressure on the swivel joint. So much so that I would not trust the TV to not kill something.

My studs are 13" on center above the fireplace - I'm thinking of modifying my bracket to hit the studs on either side

Modify in what way? What does your mount bracket look like?
If you have to drill holes close to the edge of the mount then I'd abstain from that. If you have plenty of metal around all sides of the hole and the lag bolt has good grip then it's likely fine.
If it ever fell off the wall and hurt anyone then you'd be liable because you modified the mount outside of approved specifications.

Would effect the strength and effectiveness of the mount if I cut the two other holes to hit the two other studs?

Once again, what do you mean by "cut"?

I always recommend, to people mounting TVs, to not put large TVs on swivel mounts.  The leverage provided by the large TV when handled by rough hands puts ridiculous demands on the installation.
In your case, you're blessed with 13" OC studs so maybe we can make an exception.   But if you're talking about modifying your bracket, I don't even want to see pictures of it.  Just throw it out.
Buy a new bracket that is advertised as "three stud" or as "suitable for 24 or 32" OC studs.   These have a wide wall plate, at least 48 inches wide, that in your case will easily meet with at least 3 studs.  You won't have to modify the bracket.    You'll be able to put at least 6 screws into 3 studs (maybe 8 into 4?) and the thing will be rock solid.
A quick review of how to get that right: 0) Make sure you have 2x4 wood studs.  This advice does not apply to metal studs or to furring strips above a fireplace.  1) Find the stud centers accurately.  Not with any kind of "finder".  Drill 1/16 test holes to really find them. These tiny holes will be hidden by the bracket.  2) Use 1/4" or 5/16" lag screws at least 2-1/2 inches long, with pilot holes drilled appropriate for the screw size and appropriate flat washers in front.  3) Make sure the wall is flat behind the TV so the whole wall plate is pressed tight to the wall and the bracket is not just hanging on cantilevered screws.

Thanks gor the response, I like to be able to swivel to watch TV while prepping dinner. I'll probably use the 1/4" plywood method. I live in an apartment so modifying the drywall is a no go. Thanks again guys for all the help.
